# Text inside fa-icon

Tags: html, css, icons

How to add a text inside the icon using fa icon?

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true">1</i>
```

How to add the number 1 inside the icon?

Comment: [Please, check the answered here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534068/using-numbers-with-font-awesome) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534068/using-numbers-with-font-awesome

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you should add this script into your head:

```
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/js/all.js"></script>
```

then you can use icons like this:

```
<div class="fa-4x">
  <span class="fa-layers fa-fw" style="background:MistyRose">
    <i class="fas fa-circle" style="color:Tomato"></i>
    <i class="fa-inverse fas fa-times" data-fa-transform="shrink-6"></i>
  </span>

  <span class="fa-layers fa-fw" style="background:MistyRose">
    <i class="fas fa-bookmark"></i>
    <i class="fa-inverse fas fa-heart" data-fa-transform="shrink-10 up-2" style="color:Tomato"></i>
  </span>

  <span class="fa-layers fa-fw" style="background:MistyRose">
    <i class="fas fa-play" data-fa-transform="rotate--90 grow-2"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-sun fa-inverse" data-fa-transform="shrink-10 up-2"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-moon fa-inverse" data-fa-transform="shrink-11 down-4.2 left-4"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star fa-inverse" data-fa-transform="shrink-11 down-4.2 right-4"></i>
  </span>

  <span class="fa-layers fa-fw" style="background:MistyRose">
    <i class="fas fa-calendar"></i>
    <span class="fa-layers-text fa-inverse" data-fa-transform="shrink-8 down-3" style="font-weight:900">27</span>
  </span>

  <span class="fa-layers fa-fw" style="background:MistyRose">
    <i class="fas fa-certificate"></i>
    <span class="fa-layers-text fa-inverse" data-fa-transform="shrink-11.5 rotate--30" style="font-weight:900">NEW</span>
  </span>

  <span class="fa-layers fa-fw" style="background:MistyRose">
    <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
    <span class="fa-layers-counter" style="background:Tomato">1,419</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Then you should have those icons as result:

[image: Images from font awesome]

reference [Layering, Text, and Counters | Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/layering)

Comment: Good solution, Thanks!